# Simulator not found in Product->destination (Xcode)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, git, ios7

I download a project from github

```
git clone https://github.com/alienjun/CITwirlDistortionDemo.git
```

When I try running it, I find that there aren't any simulators in the Product->destination

I can use the simulator if I create a new project (single view)

Why I can't find simulator when I use this project cloned from github?

Comment: Change the deployment target of the project to the available simulator version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the deployment target of the project to the available simulator version